# Swift: How to keep ViewControllers in exact same condition?

Tags: xcode

I have two view controllers and in ViewController 1 I have a date picker and a text field. I have another ViewController that displays what you have entered in that date picker and text field. I have a ¨change¨ button that returns you to that first view controller and a ¨doen¨button that show view controller 2. As of now the text in the textfield and the date that the user has selected, is gone every time you close the app or click the ¨change button(Go back to View controller 1).

How can i keep the text in the text field, and the selected date in the date picker.

I want the user to be able to change the information that has already been added.

Please add code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIvK3.jpg (Picture of the main storyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are showing the ViewControllers is not optimal. In the best case, when you show something new (`ViewController2`), then dismiss it, it should lead you back to the previous screen (`ViewController1`). It should not instantiate a new instance of `ViewController1`, as the segues in you case are doing.

Please note that depending on how you present the second view the solution would be different.

In case your segue from the first controller to the second is a "Show" segue, you can just add the following to your "Change" button:

```
@IBAction func changeButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

In case you have a navigation controller (I do not see such on the screenshot), then you can use

```
@IBAction func changeButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
  self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! In my case i do use a "show" segue so adding the given code worked great.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try doing is saving the data before exiting the view controller. 
In the `viewWillDisappear` method, you could add

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(textField.text, forKey: "userText")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(datePicker.date, forKey: "userDate")
```

Later, when you reopen the same view controller, in the `viewDidLoad` method, you could add

```
if  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userText") != nil {
    textField.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userText") as! String
}

if  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userDate") != nil {
    datePicker.setDate(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userDate") as! NSDate, animated: true)
}
```

I do not use date pickers very frequently, but I believe this is the correct code. Otherwise, it would be very similar. Hope this helps.

Comment: It works great for the textfield, but the date picker is reset every time I return.

Comment: Sorry. Let me fix my response

Comment: Are you sure you are using the objectForKey("userDate") each time?

Comment: Yes, I copy and pasted your text.

Comment: How about now? I updated my code to datePicker.setDate(...)

Comment: every time i return to the date is reset

Comment: Did you try using the setDate?

Comment: Yes, I copy and pasted